# Install perl-tgicl on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, software-installation, permissions, dependencies

I'm having dependency problems when trying to install perl-tgicl on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

```
sudo dpkg -i perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb

Selecting previously unselected package perl-tgicl.
(Reading database ... 229077 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking perl-tgicl (2.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of perl-tgicl:
 perl-tgicl depends on libfile-spec-perl (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libfile-spec-perl is not installed.
  Version of libfile-spec-perl on system, provided by perl-modules-5.22:all, is <none>.

dpkg: error processing package perl-tgicl (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 perl-tgicl
```

Comment: also i have tried to install libfile-spec-perl ,but i think i am not getting the correct libfile-spec-perl file from anywhere ,i am not able to understand that why its happening in newer version

Comment: What are you trying to install? Is this a perl module? Could you get it from CPAN instead?

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get -f install ?

Comment: You can get the source code  TGICL-2.1.tar.gz, here http://sourceforge.net/projects/tgicl/files/tgicl%20v2.1/

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sudo gdebi perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb` to get the dependencies installed. Then the OS is ready for building TGICL-2.1 . ( perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb will fail with the same error : libfile-spec-perl version. I.e. the package was built year 2010 : A different perl version.) ....
.... These packages were installed : `libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl lib32z1`

Building and installing TGICL-2.1 :

```
tar xvf TGICL-2.1.tar.gz
cd TGICL-2.1/
perl Build.PL
perl Build
sudo perl Build install
```

→ No issues here, Ubuntu 16.04 - 64.

Comment: perl Build.PL
Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Module::Build module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at Build.PL line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 5.

Comment: Again getting issue on this step ...                                                                     :~/Downloads/TGICL-2.1$ perl Build.PL
Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Module::Build module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at Build.PL line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 5.

Comment: Module::Build → `libmodule-build-perl` is always required for building any perl (module) → `sudo apt install libmodule-build-perl`

Comment: Thank you so much "Knud Larsen",My problem is solved now